# How to effectively visualize a decreasing sequence of sets?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a decreasing sequence of sets, expressed by a list of arrays as follow:

```
import numpy as np

D = [np.array([1, 2, 3, 4]),
     np.array([1, 2, 3]),
     np.array([1])]

print(D)
```

I would like to ask for a good way to visualize this sequence? Thank you so much for your suggestion!

---

**Update:** Thanks to @warped's instruction, this is what I'm looking for. The only problem is to show all numbers on both axis's.

```
##### Import packages
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg as la
import time
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

##### Initial conditions
N = 9
lamda = 7
mu = 2
a = 0.5
r = - np.log(a).copy()
St_Sp = np.arange(- N, N + 1)
Card = St_Sp.shape[0]

##### Define infintesimal generator
def LL(x, y):
    if x == N or x == - N: re = 0
    elif x - y == - 1: re = lamda
    elif x - y == 1: re = mu
    elif x - y == 0: re = - (mu + lamda)
    else: re = 0
    return re

def L(x):
    return - LL(x, x)

##### Define function Phi
def Phi(x):
    return max(x, 0)
Phi = np.vectorize(Phi)

##### Define vector b
b = np.array(Phi(St_Sp))

##### Define function Psi
def Psi(x):
    return L(x) / (L(x) + r)
Psi = np.vectorize(Psi)

##### Generate a Boolean vector whose all elements are False
d = np.array([0] * Card).astype(bool)

##### Define matrix A
A = np.zeros((Card, Card))
for i in range(Card):
    for j in range(Card):
        if (i != j) & (L(St_Sp[i]) != 0):
            A[i, j] = LL(St_Sp[i], St_Sp[j]) / L(St_Sp[i])
        elif (i != j) & (L(St_Sp[i]) == 0):
            A[i, j] = 0
        elif (i == j) & (Psi(St_Sp[i]) != 0):
            A[i, j] = - 1 / Psi(St_Sp[i])
        else: A[i, j] = 1

##### Row names of A
rows = np.arange(0, Card)

##### Define matrix B
B = np.zeros((Card, Card))
for i in range(Card):
    for j in range(Card):
        if i != j:
            B[i, j] = LL(St_Sp[i], St_Sp[j])
        else: B[i, j] = LL(St_Sp[i], St_Sp[j]) - r

start = time.time()        

##### Generate I_0
I = [np.array([1] * Card).astype(bool), d.copy()]

Z = np.array(b.copy())
Z = Z.astype(float)       
D = [St_Sp]
index0 = np.matmul(B, Z) <= 0
index1 = ~ index0

Y = [b.copy()]

##### Iterations
for i in range(1, Card):    
    I = [I[0] & index0, I[1] | index1]
    Z = np.array(b.copy())
    Z = Z.astype(float)

    A1 = A[np.ix_(rows[I[1]], rows[I[1]])]    
    A2 = A[np.ix_(rows[I[1]], rows[I[0]])]

    Z[I[1]] = la.solve(A1, - np.matmul(A2, Z[I[0]]))

    Y = np.concatenate((Y, [Z]))
    D.append(St_Sp[I[0]])

    index = np.matmul(B[I[0]], Z) <= 0

    index0, index1 = d.copy(), d.copy()
    index0[I[0]], index1[I[0]] = index, ~ index

    if (I[0] == index0).all() == True: break

for i, array in enumerate(D):
    plt.scatter([i]*len(array), array)
```

and get result

[image]

Comment: can you provide any visualize sample you want?

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea of how to visualize this sequence :((

Comment: What do you mean by visualise? Its contents? Its length?

Comment: @warped I mean its content, the points of each array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
for i,array in enumerate(D):
    plt.scatter([i]*len(array), array)
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I have been looking for. In [my implementation](https://imgur.com/a/EEmD8CI), there is some numbers omitted in the x-axis. Could you please help me modify the code to include all the numbers on both axis's.

Comment: sure! can you edit your question to show the code of your implementation, and the data that you are plotting?

Comment: The numbers on the y-axis are too dense, so it's fine to omit some of them. However, the numbers on the x-asis are very sparse. As such, I hope the display all of them.

Comment: Oh I'm able to do so with `plt.xticks(np.arange(0, N + 1))`.